# How to display image in Swing? in textarea?

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a chat application using `JApplet`. I have a `TextArea` where all chat messages go. Everything in working fine and smooth just as you would expect a basic chat application to do. Now i want to add support for gestures. I wanted to know, how can we show an icon in TextArea? it only takes string in `append()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be looking at [`JTextPane`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) instead of `JTextArea`.

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) which among other things, gives this demo:

[image]

Comment: Looking at how we answered the exact same thing, I will just delete mine, to avoid repeating.

Comment: @Lucifer why did you choose to improve that spam edit suggestion??

Comment: ok, got it, sorry I forgot to remove that "tick" mark while editing.